# How can I register a subscriber in Redis as a callback listener in Python

Tags: python, redis

I am creating a server in Python to support PUBSUB and using `Redis` as underlying PUBSUB implementation. The subscriber in my python looks like:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
p = r.pubsub()
p.subscribe('test')

while True:
    message = p.get_message()
    if message:
        ...  # send message to all clients who subscribed this channel/topic
    time.sleep(1)
```

It works very well but I don't like using a `while True` loop in my code. I wonder whether I can register a callback as a subscriber in Redis in python?